# Uncertainty with the !! operator (double negation)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I saw in a pull request that the double negation operator (!!) is used for the focus attribute of a text field as follows:

```
focused: !!value || value === 0,
```

As far as I know, the operator converts everything to a boolean. If it was falsy (for example 0, null, undefined,..), it will be false, otherwise, true.

In my case, i.e. if value = 0, the following comes out:

```
focused: false || true
```

The || operator here therefore makes no sense for the value 0 or am I completely confused?

Comment: The `||` is there explicitly to make the `value === 0` case truth-y. Without it, if you just had `focused: !!value,`, `value === 0` would b false-y.

Comment: `focused` is true for [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values and 0. You can verify this by running the expression on different type of values

Comment: Might not make sense for `0`, might make sense for other values?

Comment: `!value` will convert `value` to a boolean. It will be `true` if value has any *falsy* value. Then `!!value` converts it back to false or true depending if `value` was evaluated as falsy or not. The second part just excludes `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a check for numbers to get false for `''`, `""`, `false`, `NaN`, `undefined` and `null`. Other bjects, like functions, arrays or simple objects returns `true`;

```js
const check = value => !!value || value === 0;

console.log(check(0));
console.log(check(1));
console.log(check(''));
console.log(check(""));
console.log(check(false));
console.log(check(NaN));
console.log(check(null));
console.log(check(undefined));
console.log(check({}));
```

Comment: I would say it's a check for any falsy value but `0`

Comment: i would say it's a check for truthy values or zero ...

Comment: Ok, so in my case focused is true for truthy values and 0. Like @adiga mentioned in the comments above? Now it makes sense to me too  ^^. Thanks :)